# How can i parse json string without the opening and closing string quotes?

Tags: javascript, json

How can i parse the following json string without the opening and closing quotes? Its seems like javascript JSON.parse function is parsing the string with the quotes! hence throws a syntax error.

This is my string;

```
"[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "pms.category",
        "fields": {
            "name": "Rent",
            "add_date": "2011-07-28 01:33:21",
            "agent": 3,
            "category_type": "I",
            "add_user": 3,
            "desc": "Rent"
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 2,
        "model": "pms.category",
        "fields": {
            "name": "Deposit Rent",
            "add_date": "2011-07-28 01:33:21",
            "agent": 3,
            "category_type": "I",
            "add_user": 3,
            "desc": "Rent Deposit"
        }
    }
]"
```

Edit:
Something interesting is that when i run this string of my development machine, it is parsed correctly, but on the production server it fails.

Comment: If the quotes are part of the data, then it is a string, not JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the opening and closing quotes, and then parse the string:

```
s = s.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');
var jsonDoc = JSON.parse(s);
```

Additionally, file a bug report with the author of the program or library that emits malformed JSON.

Comment: Still no luck, am running in on chrome debugger and am still getting syntax error! try copy the string and run it on the chrome console, this is amazing!!

Comment: @gath Feel free to ask a new question about the malformed JSON (include a link to http://pastebin.com/ if it's longer than, say, 20 lines) if you don't find the problem yourself. Also feel free to slap the author of that malformed JSON.

Comment: @philag, replaced the external double quotes with single quotes worked well. JSON.parse(s.replace(/^"|"$/g,"'")). Thanks lots.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably remove the outer quotes from your string...

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/^"|"$/g,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

1.This should be your JSON format otherwise, it WILL NOT be parsed properly by JSON.parse

```
[
        {
            "pk": 1,
            "model": "pms.category",
            "fields": {
                "name": "Rent",
                "add_date": "2011-07-28 01:33:21",
                "agent": 3,
                "category_type": "I",
                "add_user": 3,
                "desc": "Rent"
            }
        },
        {
            "pk": 2,
            "model": "pms.category",
            "fields": {
                "name": "Deposit Rent",
                "add_date": "2011-07-28 01:33:21",
                "agent": 3,
                "category_type": "I",
                "add_user": 3,
                "desc": "Rent Deposit"
            }
        }
    ]
```

2.Include json2.js from the github repository inbetween your head tags.