# Whats wrong with this JSON syntax?

Tags: javascript, json

Am trying this on my chrome debugger console, and am getting a **SyntaxError**;

```
JSON.parse("[{"name":"gath","age":10}]");
>SyntaxError
```

What is the correct way of parsing the JSON string?
Please note this question is a follow up to my [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040203/how-can-i-parse-json-string-without-the-opening-and-closing-string-quotes) one, which am yet to get an answer!

Comment: For the record, the JSON syntax is correct, but you cannot have unescaped double quotes inside a double-quoted string in JavaScript (and probably in no other language ;)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape your double-quotes.

```
JSON.parse("[{\"name\":\"gath\",\"age\":10}]");
```

or, for better readabilty, define the string with single quotes:

```
JSON.parse('[{"name":"gath","age":10}]');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.parse("[{\"name\":\"gath\",\"age\":10}]");
```

You cant have double quotes inside double quotes

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the " 
or do JSON.parse('[{"name":"gath","age":10}]');

Answer (score 0):

Enclose it in single quotes and it will parse correctly.

```
JSON.parse('[{"name":"gath","age":10}]');


Object
age: 10
name: "gath"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
JSON.parse("[{"name":"gath","age":10}]");
```

With

```
JSON.parse('[{"name":"gath","age":10}]');
```

Comment: Why not? Both `"` and `'` are supported in JSON.

Comment: *A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in **double quotes**, using backslash escapes.* [Source.](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: Also, it results in a Syntax Error in the Chrome developer console.

Comment: NP - re-reading my comments, I came off as a bit abrasive; I didn't intend to - apologies.

Comment: Also, here's a [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response) SO question.